# When I apply my texture to the roof it makes a shadow on the right hand corner. How can I fix this?

Tags: texturing, materials

[image]

[image]

When I created the roof I only used a solidify modifier. Maybe that can be the reason why but I am not sure?

Comment: Hello, are you sure that the unwrap is correct? Maybe check the UV Editor, or please share the object (roof only): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I am new to blender so I am not sure if the unwrap is correct. I did attach a screenshot with the roof only and the UV editor.

Comment: could you please pack the image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share the roof? In your image we can't guess what's happening with the stretched map

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, but I figured out what the problem was. I had duplicate vertices on the roof.